# how to migrating application jboss fuse standalone to jboss fuse openshift

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, openshift, jbossfuse

I'm a newbie in DevOps. So I want to migrate an application from JBoss fuse in my laptop to Openshift fuse. How do I do that?

I have tried using oc command to build my source code on laptop but it doesn't work.

[here is the error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBD2l.png)

thank you in advance

Comment: The statement "but it doesn't work" is not useful. Provide the commands that you are using and the error messages. Edit your question with this information.

Comment: done I put some error's image to my question

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be the [oc bug 1398330](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398330), which was merged into ocp and is in OCP v3.5.0.7 or newer.
Please test with the newest version.